# How do I list the child of a child page

Tags: php, child-pages

I was wondering as to how I can list the child of a child pages in wordpress.

Here is what I have set up.

```
Videos (Parent)
 -Music Videos(child)
  --Video 1 (Child of Child)
  --Video 2 (Child of Child)

 -Performances (Child)
  --Video 1 (Child Of Child)
  --Video 2 (Child Of Child)
```

I want to list all the "child of child" of the parent page "VIDEOS".

I know this code only list the "child" pages but not the child of childs.

```
<?php
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
<div class="child-thumb">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
<a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif;
?>
```

I want to do this without having to add anything to my functions.php

What do I need to add to make this happen. I have five child of child pages under the Parent page.

Comment: Here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113308/get-pages-display-child-then-grandchild-pages?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why you are querying for posts by your custom query? We have `WP_Query` class and `get_posts` function to do this.

```
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
```

became

```
$pages = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
    'order' => 'ASC'
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
```

Next, you should use `get_page_children` function ([get_page_children on codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children)) to generate tree list. `get_page_children` does not query to database each time we want to generate list of children, but is using list of all posts which is stored in `$pages` variable.

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <?php if ($page->post_parent == 0): ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
                <?php $children = get_page_children($page->ID, $pages); ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($children as $child): ?>
                        <?php if ($child->post_parent == $page->ID): ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php echo $child->post_title; ?>
                                <?php $granchildren = get_page_children($child->ID, $pages); ?>
                                <ul>
                                    <?php foreach ($granchildren as $grandchild): ?>
                                        <li><?php echo $grandchild->post_title; ?></li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

EDIT. I think that this will fit to your expectation now:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'page')); ?>
<?php $children = get_page_children($post->ID, $posts); ?>
<?php foreach ($children as $child): ?>
    <?php if ($child->post_parent == $post->ID): ?>
        <div>
            <h2><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></h2>
            <ul>
                <?php $grandchildren = get_page_children($child->ID, $posts); ?>
                <?php foreach ($grandchildren as $grandchild): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $grandchild->post_title; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to list them all together, Like we do the post on the homepage. Like whenever I add a new grandchild page it automatically updates on the videos page.

Comment: So you should use only once `get_page_children`, it will give you all children of given post parent ID

Comment: Do I copy the code just as is and use it?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your code above is doing.

Comment: Look at answer now, I think that this is what you want to achieve

Comment: You are being really helpful and I appreciate that. What about linking them to the pages

Comment: The best way you will do this is to create [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). You could also change theme files, but I will not recommend it because of overriding changes by updates.

Comment: Shortcode to link them in this manor? `<a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">`

Comment: or is this the correct way to make them link `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($get_page_children($post->ID,); ?>`

Comment: I figured it out `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($grandchild->ID); ?>"><?php echo $grandchild->post_title; ?></a>`

Comment: How do I get the thumbnail attached to the page? I tried using `the_post_thumbnail` and `get_the_post_thumbnail`